# connecting tables in sql apex?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

hi i created tables using sql :-

```
create tables
create table customer (
    cust_id                             number not null constraint customer_id_pk primary key,
    cust_first                     varchar2(4000),
    cust_last                      varchar2(4000),
    cust_city                      varchar2(255), 

)
;

create table medicine (
    med_id                             number not null constraint medicine_id_pk primary key,
    med_name                       varchar2(255),
    med_info                       varchar2(4000),
    med_prise                       number
)
;

create table the_order (
    order_id                             number not null constraint the_order_id_pk primary key,
    order_date                     date,
    order_buyer                    varchar2(4000),
    order_med                      varchar2(4000)
)
;
```

how do i connect the tables together into the order table i am using Apex to make a project.
i know its about foreign key but in the apex platform to show the forms as a report on one big table ?

Comment: anyone can help me  ?

Comment: Have a look at this overview to Quick SQL, which is built into APEX (SQL Workshop > Utilities > Quick SQL). It covers foreign keys: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux2eISE9cSQ

Answer (score 0):

Defining foreign keys is something done on the database, for a number of good reasons.

Your queries will work without them, but won't perform as well, and you could get dirty data over time.

It's all about the SQL. APEX is just a conduit to get the data from the database into a web page in front of the user's eyes.

You have a table design issue.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you follow their [best practices](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeutl/using-quick-SQL.html#GUID-89A0BA18-C64D-4165-9B4D-82D043AFEC67), it should figure out foreign keys and indexes for you.

## Example

### Quick SQL

```markdown
customers
    first_name /nn
    last_name /nn
    city

medicines
    name /nn
    info
    price num /nn

orders
    date /nn
    customer_id /nn

    order_lines
        medicine_id /nn
        medicine_name /nn
        medicine_price num /nn
        quantity num /nn
        total num /nn
```

### Generated SQL

```sql
-- create tables
create table customers (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint customers_id_pk primary key,
    first_name                     varchar2(255 char) not null,
    last_name                      varchar2(255 char) not null,
    city                           varchar2(255 char)
)
;

create table medicines (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint medicines_id_pk primary key,
    name                           varchar2(255 char) not null,
    info                           varchar2(4000 char),
    price                          number not null
)
;

create table orders (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint orders_id_pk primary key,
    customer_id                    number
                                   constraint orders_customer_id_fk
                                   references customers on delete cascade not null,
    the_date                       date not null
)
;

-- table index
create index orders_i1 on orders (customer_id);

create table order_lines (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint order_lines_id_pk primary key,
    order_id                       number
                                   constraint order_lines_order_id_fk
                                   references orders on delete cascade,
    medicine_id                    number
                                   constraint order_lines_medicine_id_fk
                                   references medicines on delete cascade not null,
    medicine_name                  varchar2(255 char) not null,
    medicine_price                 number not null,
    quantity                       number not null,
    total                          number not null
)
;

-- table index
create index order_lines_i1 on order_lines (medicine_id);
create index order_lines_i2 on order_lines (order_id);
```